# Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I tried to show modal using jquery, but to no avail.

I've tried to rearrange my jquery place and researching through other questions but I can't find any answer to my problem.

Here's the button

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <a onclick="addmhsForm();" href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><span>Tambah Mahasiswa</span></a>
</div>
```

Here's where I place my script and jquery

```
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/api.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my custom javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Here's where I place ajax script
});

function addmhsForm() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#add-error-bag").hide();
        $('#addModal').modal('show');
    });
}
```

I expect the code to show the modal, alas what I find is an error message like this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addmhsForm is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

**UPDATE**

I found that my problem lies in @include or the partial view containing the modal.

Whenever I remove the @include in my laravel, all .js files will appear in Google Developer Tools but my button will do nothing when clicked.

Though, when I put it again the problem reappear.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `api.js` is actually being loaded in the page?

Comment: Can you show me your page content?

Comment: @charlietfl Apparently when I see it in Network Tab of Google Developer Tools, it doesnt show any script at all.

Comment: @Dhananjay Kyada Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, is it the code or the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my limited understanding, I tried to bruteforce my way to solve this problem and turns out the culprit is a HTML tag namely

> Textarea

This Problematic Code

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="alamat" id="alamat"/>
```

The Solve

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="alamat" id="alamat"></textarea>
```